# Jasmine breaks when instantiating class

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I'm trying to write tests for our Angular 2 app with Jasmine. Followed a few tutorials, tried a lot. It works with basic tests, but once I make an instance of a component or try to mock it I just get no testresults. According to [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#first-app-tests) it's 'That's Jasmine saying "things are so bad that I'm not running any tests."'

Strangely enough, BlobViewModel does work. Whenever I comment or delete the 'this.const = new Constants();' it works again. Tried with multiple classes, always get the same results.. No logs/errors in chrome.

We're using Angular RC4 with Jasmine 2.4.1.
This is my .spec file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

import { Constants } from './shared/app.constants';

describe('component test', () => {
     beforeEach(function () {
        this.const = new Constants(); // THIS BREAKS IT
    });
    it('Tests', () => {
        //Tests come here
        //this.const.Signalr();
    });
});

describe('1st tests', () => {
    it('true is true', () => expect(true).toEqual(true));});

describe('BlobViewModel', () => {
    var id = 1;
    var localhost = "http//localhost";
    var fullpath = "http//fullpathtoapplication.com";
    var printername = "Printy print";
    var papersize = "A4";
    var blobmodel = new BlobViewModel(id, localhost, fullpath, printername, papersize);
    it('BlobviewModel aanmaken', () => {
        expect(blobmodel.ID).toEqual(id);
        expect(blobmodel.FullLocalUrl).toEqual(localhost);
        expect(blobmodel.FullPath).toEqual(fullpath);
        expect(blobmodel.PrinterName).toEqual(printername);
        expect(blobmodel.PaperSize).toEqual(papersize);
    });
});
```

HTML file for the .spec runner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="../js/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <!-- #1. add the system.js library -->
    <script src="../js/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/Systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        // #2. Configure systemjs to use the .js extension
        //     for imports from the app folder
        System.config({
            packages: {
                '../app': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
            }
        });

        // #3. Import the spec file explicitly
        System.import('../app/file.spec.js')

      // #4. wait for all imports to load ...
      //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
      //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
      //     or explain what went wrong.
      .then(window.onload)
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured it out, had to import the "Reflect-metadata" package in the html file:

```
 <script src="../js/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
```